# Uncaught Reference Error my() is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Place Order" onclick="my()">


<script type="text/javascript">

  <% String resp= session.getAttribute("jsonData").toString();%>
  const jso="<%=resp%>"
function my(){

    alert(jso);


  }




</script>
```

I want to get JSP variable and store in javascript and show in alert but when i di this my onclick function return function my is not defined.

Comment: Right-click the web page and click view-source and paste relevant parts of that instead of JSP

Comment: I recommend you give the button an ID and do `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { const jso = "<%=resp%>"; document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", (e) => { alert(jso); }); })` and remove the inline event handler

Comment: mplungjan it shows nothing in console now.

Comment: What console? You alert things. If you want it in the console, use console.log and if it does not work, then there will likely be an error instead

Comment: mplungjan it shows nothing not alert and not error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a JavaScript error in this line:
`const jso="<%=resp%>"`

`resp` comes from an attribute called `jsonData`, and therefore I assume that it contains JSON. Properties and string values in JSON are enclosed in double quotes. The following little example already shows the error I expect you're getting:

```
const jso="{"key": "value"}"
```

The opening `"` isn't closed by the last `"`, but by the first one in your JSON. In other words - you're outputting invalid JavaScript.

The best solution is to properly escape the JSON. I recommend using [Apache Commons Text 1.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.10.0). With the proper import:

```
const jso="<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(resp)%>"
```

This will properly escape any unsafe characters, including `"`, in `resp` before outputting it.

Comment: It work like a charm thank you so much. I want a small help from you how can i convert again this jso to JSON

Comment: var response=JSON.parse(resp) // This Work fine
    console.log(response)
    response.json().then(data => {
        //order is generated successfully
        console.log(data)


        initiateClientModule(data)


    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        alert("error in initiating payment")
    })
but this give error responses.jsp:19 Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function
    at my (responses.jsp:19:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (responses.jsp:10:83) what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This must work. If not, then there is something else going on

Here I do not add the

```
<% String resp= session.getAttribute("jsonData").toString();%>
```

for obvious reasons

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const jso = "<%=resp%>";
  document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    alert(jso);
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="myButton" class="btn" value="Place Order">
```